# Google Tag Manager > dataLayer variable find and replace with javascript variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I'm having trouble with a Google Tag Manager dataLayer variable which does not contain the right information.

The "sku" field is not named correctly and I need to change it into "variant". I'm trying to achieve this with a custom JavaScript variable in GTM but whatever I'm trying I'm not able to find and replace "sku" with "variant" in the products array.

All help is very much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,
Adriaan

[image]

Comment: Super brief summary: your CJ variable would need to take the DL variable, transform the entire array (ie. change "sku" to "variant"), and then return the modified array.

Comment: That's exactly the case nyen!

Comment: Can you post the code for your CJ variable, tags, and triggers?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Custom JavaScript Variable which uses the old array and replaces the product parameters, something like that:

```
var arr = {{YourProductArray}}; //check if its a valid array

arr.forEach(function(prod, index, array){
  if(prod.sku) {
    arr[index].variant = prod.sku;
    arr[index].sku = ""; //reset the value if needed
  }
});

return arr;
```