# How can I replace parameter names in the dataLayer using javascript in GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have an array containing ecommerce order info that I am pulling from the dataLayer into GTM. I have defined this order info as a variable that I want to pass on to a TikTok pixel for a Payment Complete event.

The problem I face is that the TikTok pixel expects the key name "id" to be called "content_id" and the key name "name" to be called "content_name". I understand that it is possible to perform a search and replace using a Custom Javascript variable in GTM, and then send the edited array on to the pixel. But I cannot figure out how to do the search and replace part using JavaScript. Here is what I am working with, this is what is in my variable:

```
[
  {
    id: "JBLANC015",
    name: "Blanc Diffuser, Maldivian Breeze",
    category: "Diffusers",
    price: "29.90",
    quantity: "3"
  },
  {
    id: "CH-AH-SHK-GREEN",
    name: "Hand Gesture Candle, Shaka  Green",
    category: "Candles",
    price: "39.90",
    quantity: "1"
  }
]
```

This is just an example, the array may contain more or less products, all instances of "id" and "name" need to be replaced with the correct ones that the pixel will recognize.

Here is an [extra-explanatory screencast video](https://videoshare.nextlevelbros.com/conversations/af586468-2f38-5968-827f-a4210f4f3e6c) in case that helps.

I have tried this:

```
function(){
   var str = {{my array variable}};
   return str.replace("id", "content_id");
}
```

But no success.

Edit. After understanding the difference between dealing with strings and arrays I got something like this which is working for changing one key at a time:

```
function(){
var products = 
[
  {
    name: "Hand Gesture Candle, Shaka  Green",
    id: "21834",
    price: "39.900000",
    brand: "Candlehand",
    category: "Candles"
  }
]
;
products.forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.content_name = obj.name;
  delete obj.name;
});
return products;
}
```

This does the job, but not when I plug in a variable that is pulling the array straight and live from the website.

```
function(){
var products = {{my array variable}};
products.forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.content_name = obj.name;
  delete obj.name;
});
return products;
}
```

When I use this version seen above with the variable the "name" key gets deleted and I do not get the changed "content_name" key in the returned data. No doubt something simple that escapes me.

There is a similar question here [Google Tag Manager > dataLayer variable find and replace with javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642299/google-tag-manager-datalayer-variable-find-and-replace-with-javascript-variable) but could not get the suggested answer to work for me or to extract a working solution from it.

Any help will with this would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed I post this new answer to your updated question.

I tried `delete` as well, but as you experienced it will remove the assigned value as well.

But you can also create a new array, which returns the changed products:

```js
function(){
  var products = 
  [
    {
      name: "Hand Gesture Candle, Shaka  Green",
      id: "21834",
      price: "39.900000",
      brand: "Candlehand",
      category: "Candles"
    }
  ];
  
  var changes = [];
  products.forEach(function(obj) {
    var product = {
      content_id: obj.id,
      content_name: obj.name,
      price: obj.price,
      brand: obj.brand,
      category: obj.category
    };
    changes.push(product);
  });
  return changes;
}
```

My mistake in the other answer was to use `let`. We should use `var` instead, since `let` is pretty recent.

For the future, please read [how much research is expected of you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) here at SO. The expectation is that you don't try once, fail and immediately go asking. You know you must learn JavaScript, so check tutorials and documentation.
Beginner questions are fine, but you have to show you have done your own work to get to that point.

See below for a quick demonstration of above code (added a `console.log()` call).

```js
(function(){
  var products = 
  [
    {
      name: "Hand Gesture Candle, Shaka  Green",
      id: "21834",
      price: "39.900000",
      brand: "Candlehand",
      category: "Candles"
    }
  ]
  ;
  var changes = [];
  products.forEach(function(obj) {
    var product = {
      content_id: obj.id,
      content_name: obj.name,
      price: obj.price,
      brand: obj.brand,
      category: obj.category
    };
    console.log(product);
    changes.push(product);
  });
  return changes;
})();
```

Comment: This is amazing Peter and works perfectly. I have accepted the answer but lack the reputation for an upvote. Seeing your code I can understand what is going on with the nested var, the objects and push to be able to recreate something similar for future use cases. I was too ambitious for my level to think I was close to putting something like this together. I did spend 20+ hours on research and testing and understood what was missing but lacked the fundamentals to execute. Also did not want to create a wall of text with stuff I tried, I knew the 1st example I posted was very wrong. Danke!

Comment: Sure thing, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

#### Write a new array

`str.replace` is the `replace` function for a string, not an array. Here you are dealing with objects inside an array.
You cannot just guess a function that could work and then ask a question here. Please check the documentation and find JavaScript tutorials how to use Strings, Objects and Arrays.
The documentation already contains examples you can learn from.

Here are some links to JavaScript documentation:

- [MDN: JavaScript String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)
- [MDN: JavaScript Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [MDN: JavaScript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

An easy to understand solution would be to create a new array.
Loop over every object in the array and every property in the object and just create a new object from that. There is no need to get fancy. Just use a loop or two if you need them.
See working snippet below.

#### Example code

```js
let arr = [
  {
    id: "JBLANC015",
    name: "Blanc Diffuser, Maldivian Breeze",
    category: "Diffusers",
    price: "29.90",
    quantity: "3"
  },
  {
    id: "CH-AH-SHK-GREEN",
    name: "Hand Gesture Candle, Shaka  Green",
    category: "Candles",
    price: "39.90",
    quantity: "1"
  }
];

let trackingArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  let obj = {};
  for(var k in arr[i]) {
    switch(k) {
      case "id":
        obj.content_id = arr[i][k];
        break;
      case "name":
        obj.content_name = arr[i][k];
        break;
      default:
        obj[k] = arr[i][k];
        break;
    }
  }
  
  console.log(obj);
  trackingArray.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, unfortunately I get an error "Error at line 2, character 1: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better" in GTM when using this code.  Something about the engine used in GTM which I think is also why a ton of suggestions for similar issues found on stackoverlfow are not working for me. 

I have updated my question with an example that is close to what I seek that reflects a better understanding of the difference between strings and arrays that I learned in the meantime. I'm not a dev but a marketer, go easy please.

Comment: Oh this is a site for developers, we assume peers here, sure. Thanks for posting your code. I will try with a new answer.